# Access DB data that was exported from an AWS RDS snapshot to S3 from an AWS RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I want to convert some my AWS RDS snapshots to S3 to help cost savings. I am converting a test snapshot to S3 now. After the DB data is in S3 how can I access the data later if needed from a AWS Aurora DB?

Let's say a customer needs to access the old data that was stored in the snapshot and the snapshot is gone and is exported to S3. How do I bring it back so it can be used again in an AWS Aurora RDS instance?

I have read that you can just point the AWS RDS instance to the S3 location but can not figure out how.

I am currently using 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.1 for my AWS RDS instance(and that is what the snapshots were taken of) and when I convert it back I probably will want to use the same.

The goal of this is :
AWS Live RDS > Snapshot > S3 > S3 Glacier
Then if we need the data back:
S3 Glacier > S3 > Access from Live AWS RDS

Please note that I am not a MySQL master (yet!).

Comment: Are you trying to do this via the CLI or via the Management Console?

Answer (score -1):

In the Management Console, If you go to the list of databases, there is a 'Restore from S3' button that should lead you to a way to add via the S3 bucket.

The AWS CLI also has `restore-db-instance-from-s3` which has options such as:

```
--source-engine <value>
--source-engine-version <value>
--s3-bucket-name <value>
[--s3-prefix <value>]
--s3-ingestion-role-arn <value>
```

There are also plenty more options at:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/restore-db-instance-from-s3.html

Comment: Awesome! I will try it soon. Thank you